# How to copy data from a webpage table to .csv file?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a website from which I need to copy the data to a CSV file.

The website is https://in.investing.com/equities/india

I need to download the data displayed in the table into CSV file

I have done the Selenium part of the code

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("stocksFilter"));
          Select dropdown= new Select(element);
          System.out.println(name);
          dropdown.selectByVisibleText(name);
          //Waiting for table containing data to appear
          WebElement ele2 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 100))
          .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("cross_rate_markets_stocks_1")));
```

The table is `cross_rate_markets_stocks_1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code i have done for that site too dd this code after the selenium part

firstly declare these

```
Document HTMLpageContent ;
        Element table ;
        Elements header , bodyrows , rowContent;
        String data="",val="",sy;
        File dir_1;
        File parent;
        PrintWriter pw ;
```

then add this part after the selenium selection

```
//Creating a file of name 'filename'
        dir_1=new File(path+"/<filename you want to save>.csv");
        parent=dir_1.getParentFile();
        if(!parent.exists())
          parent.mkdirs();
        pw = new PrintWriter(dir_1);
        sy=driver.getPageSource();//Getting the HTML source code
        HTMLpageContent = Jsoup.parse(sy);
        table = HTMLpageContent.getElementById("cross_rate_markets_stocks_1");
        header = table.getElementsByTag("th");
        bodyrows = table.getElementsByTag("tr");
        for(Element headerData:header)
          data+=headerData.text()+",";//Storing column names in string data
        data=data.substring(0,(data.length()-1));
        data+="\n";
        for(Element row:bodyrows)
        {
          rowContent=row.getElementsByTag("td");
          for(Element rowData:rowContent)
          {//Extracting data of a row and storing
            val=rowData.text();//Some data may contain , in there data
            if(checkComma(val))
            {
              val=val.substring(0,val.indexOf(','))+val.substring(val.indexOf(',')+1);
            }
            data+=val+",";
          }
          data=data.substring(0,(data.length()-1));
          data+="\n";
        }
        pw.write(data);
        pw.close();
        System.out.println("Successfull in generating "+name+".csv");
```

Comment: lemme try this first

Comment: keep ur code part in a try block and catch for excepions